# parsing set variable string in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We have web activity and it always return below string with value change (value is dynamic everyday). We would need to extract key value. Please advise how to achieve this in Azure Data Factory activities.

Set Activity return value : Value= "{"aws_access_key_id":"XE6MX","aws_secret_access_key":"sgD6zEe"}"

We would like to get aws_access_key_id value XE6MX in separate variable so we can pass it to subsequent activities. And this value id dynamic and changes every day

tried with replace and search functions but couldn't work out.

Comment: If you have a string then I think you can wrap it with the json function and then access the properties.  Something like json(<put your value here).aws_access_key_id .  I may not have the exact syntax but that is the general idea - tell it that it is json then access the properties.  If the value where it is coming from is already json then you don't need the json function.

Comment: the web activity output returning the value above shared, can I use JSON function on this, I am trying to write this in another set variable activity

Comment: should be able to if it is interpreted as a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the data from web activity output, try to set the value- of the variable in the Set variable activity assign the output like this

```
 @activity('GetWebActivity').output.aws_access_key_id
```

Comment: I tried this in first place but getting the below error if I make any change to it.  activity('Web1').output.aws_access_key_id' cannot be evaluated because property 'aws_access_key_id' doesn't exist, avaiable properties are 'value, contentType, id,attributes, tags, ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders

Answer (score 0):

```
{ 
"name": "var1",
"value": "{\"aws_access_key_id\":\"XE6MX\",\"aws_secret_access_key\":\"sgD6zEe\"}"
}
```

If you have set variable activity output like above, you can convert the JSON string from the variable to JSON and then access the required property as suggested in comments.

```
@json(variables('var1')).aws_access_key_id
```

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Check if your web activity returns the same JSON string, and if its same, you can get the output from web activity output itself.

```
@json(<web activity output expression for the JSON string>).aws_access_key_id
```

Comment: Awesome, it worked like charm. Appreciate for help.